# xlsx file not being exported django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am calling ajax request from frontend to export data in excel sheet.

**js**

```
function exportData(){

  create_spinner("Please wait while we export data.");

  var agent = $("#agent").val()
  var dateRange = $("#dateRangeValue").val()
  var queue = $("#queue").val()
  var direction = $("#direction").val()
  var department = $("#department").val()
  var serviceLevel = $("#sl").val()

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/call-record-api/export-data/",
    data: {
      "agent": agent,
      "dateRange": dateRange,
      "queue": queue,
      "direction": direction,
      "department": department,
      "serviceLevel": serviceLevel,
    },
    success: function(resultData) {
        console.log("success");
        hide_spinner();
    },
    error: function (err) {
      console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      create_spinner("Couldn't export data. Please try again");
      setTimeout(function(){ hide_spinner()}, 1000);
    }
  }); 
}
```

I have gone through [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#xlsx-binary-spreadsheet-endpoints) and implemented the same.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^call-record-api/export-data/$', ExportCallRecordView.as_view({"post":"list"})),
```

**views.py**

```
class ExportCallRecordView(XLSXFileMixin, ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        calls = export_customized_calls(self.request)
        print(calls.count())
        return calls

    serializer_class = CallRecordSerializer
    renderer_classes = [XLSXRenderer]
    filename = 'call_record_export.xlsx'
```

But i cannot see the file getting downloaded. However i can see `success` in browser console and `235` as call count in server console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't download files directly with ajax. You have to use tricks like this (taken from a github repo):

```
// jQuery ajax
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: params,
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        // check for a filename
        var filename = "";
        var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }

        var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
        var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });

        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        } else {
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            if (filename) {
                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                // safari doesn't support this yet
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                } else {
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                window.location = downloadUrl;
            }

            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
        }
    }
});
```

Or if you don't mind converting your POST request in to GET request:

```
window.location = `/<download_url>/?param1=${encodeURIComponent(param1)}`
```

Comment: I also did research at my end. I agree that it's not quite simple with ajax. I rather changed it to GET request to a different url. It's working.